# How can I change the "Delete?" label in a Djano Inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'd like to replace the default "Delete?" label in TabularInLine to be something like "X". Is there a way to do this in Django directly or do I have to change it after the page loads with JS?
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVcpc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide your own version of the Django Admin template that generates that page. To do this you would save a template with the same name and the same parent directory path within your project's template directory (see further documentation and recommendations here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). Based on the simple nature of the desired change it would be advisable to only modify that section of the template using this method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template.